# Crear xml con XmlWriter y C#

Tags: c#, xml

Estoy intentando escribir en un archivo xml lo siguiente:

```
<infoAdicional>
    <campoAdicional nombre="Nº DocCompra">0247168886</campoAdicional>
</infoAdicional>
```

He probado muchos fragmentos de código y referencias pero hasta ahora solo he conseguido hacer esto:

```
<infoAdicional>
    <campoAdicional xmlns="Nº DocCompra">0247168886</campoAdicional>
</infoAdicional>
```

No sé si represente la misma información, o como cambiar "xmlns" por "nombre".
Recién estoy tratando de crear un xml y se dificulta mucho.

El código que estoy empleando es:

```
 XmlWriter writer = null;

        try
        {

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            writer = XmlWriter.Create(m_Document, settings);

            writer.WriteComment("sample XML fragment");


            writer.WriteStartElement("infoAdicional");


            string prefix = writer.LookupPrefix("nombre");
            writer.WriteStartElement(prefix, "campoAdicional", "Nº DocCompra");
            writer.WriteString("0247168886");
            writer.WriteEndElement();


            writer.WriteEndElement();

            // Write the XML to file and close the writer.
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }

        finally
        {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.Close();
        }
```

Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, por favor, modifica tu pregunta y añadí el código que te esta presentando problemas, para así poder ayudarte mejor..

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar [`XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlWriter_WriteAttributeString_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_) para hacerlo, simplemente, pasamos un el parámetro `prefix` como `null` y `ns` también.

Nos quedaría algo así..

```
writer.WriteStartElement("campoAdicional");
writer.WriteAttributeString(null, "nombre", null, "Nº DocCompra");
writer.WriteString("0247168886");
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

De esta manera, el xml generado será el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--sample XML fragment-->
<infoAdicional>
    <campoAdicional nombre="Nº DocCompra">0247168886</campoAdicional>
</infoAdicional>
```

Saludos

Comment: Excelente estimado, te estoy muy agradecido.